# Reputation & badge items not fully clickable

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-feed

In Stack Exchange Android app feed, not all items are fully clickable.

Specifically, reputation notification items are only clickable *in the text area itself*. If you tap a little bit outside of the text, the notification won't open. It just does the default Android list item selection animation as can be seen in the screenshot below. This a minor annoyance, but would be nice to fix.

[image: Screen shot of tapping in the box but outside of the text]

This also happens on badge updates.

[image: Tapping not on text of badge update]

Comment: Repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta). Compared to the question/answer posts, the layout bound for reputation and badge is indeed only for its text, not stretch to the size of the list item itself.